# jquery short hand for parent, children

Tags: jquery, parent, relative-path, children

i keep on having to affect elements relevant to other elements but my methods see a little amateur!

ie to

```
//  <div> <div> <div> <ul> matched item where script is called from </ul> </div> </div> <a class="postMore">LINK</a> </div>
```

i use;

```
$(this).parent('div').parent('div').parent('div').children('a.postMore').css('display','block');
```

which seems a little cumbersome. Is there a better way to handle relative elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple ways to [traverse the DOM with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/), so you just need to identify the pattern in your html structure, and use the most relevant methods.

In your example this should do what you want and it allows for much more flexibility.

```
$(this).closest('div:has(a.postMore)').find('a.postMore');
```

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/j2Wgv/

---

- [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) will go upwards the DOM
  until if finds an elements that
  matches the selector we passed it as an argument.
- Our selector is `div:has(a.postMore)` which means a `div` that contains a link with class `postMore`
- And then we use the [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to reach the actual link.

Comment: brilliant - thanks gaby! Are there any processing implications for find?

Comment: @daniel, do you mean efficiency issues ? No, `.find()` is the most commonly used method for traversing downward the DOM hierarchy and if the specified selector allows, it uses native browser-methods for its work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.closest()` which will search upwards through the DOM tree. So if you give your div that contains `a.postMore` a class, you can use `$(this).closest('class').children('a.postMore')`.
Documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: you do not have to give a class to the container div. There is the [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector just for this..

Comment: nice, I did not know that. Thanks and +1 for your answer.